# Resizable DIV container with header/body/footer where body is scrollable

Tags: jquery, css, overflow

I've missed something very simple, but I'm unable to get this resizable `div` container to work the way I want.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingmedia/yrJre/

My problem is that the body is not overflowing and triggering the scrollbar. The contents of the `div` remain the same size when the container is resized.

```
+------------------------------+
| HEADER                       |
+------------------------------+
| BODY                       |X|
|                            |-|
|                            | |
|                            | |
|                            | |
|                            | |
|                            | |
|                            | |
|                            | |
|                            |-|
|                            |X|
+------------------------------+
| FOOTER                       |
+------------------------------+
```

Illustration above of what I want.

I want to create a resizable `div` where the body content is scrollable, but the header/footer remain visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved your problem by adding a resize handler:

```
$(".filter-form").resizable().resize(function()
{
    var bodyHeight = $(this).height() - 40;

    $('.filter-body').css('height', bodyHeight + "px");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yrJre/3/

Answer (score 0):

So you want a middle area which is scrollable if I understand correctly?

This, most of the time can be a little tricky! You need to make that area 100% the height of the body element minus the height of the header and the height of the footer.

To acieve this I like the following solution:

```
div {
  overflow:auto;
  border:solid;
  margin:100px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;

}
```

Here the absolute position gives the element 100% height, and the margin deducts height equal to the space you want reserved for your footer and header.

See demo:

http://jsbin.com/ucahom/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an initial height. Also, the body should be set to resize:both (or just vertical if you wish).

```
.filter-form
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.filter-body
{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    resize: both;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Here is my jsfidle example. Notice the javascript resizable is also commented out.
http://jsfiddle.net/3ZuP4/

Comment: The resize handlers are not around the parent now